# How to verify ssl certificate?

Tags: python, validation, ssl-certificate

im working on dns masking. Im asking user to provide URL for masking and SSL certificate. I need to validate whether the certificate user provided is of valid format or not. The problem is if user doesnot provide valid certificate apache doesn't restart. Im using python.

I've tried some solutions provided here but couldn't validate ssl certificate.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!